# Is SNMP4J incompatible with MIB Brower?

Tags: java, snmp4j

Mib Brower can pick up and display details when I use command line trap
[image]

[image]

However, when I trap using SNMP4J, Mib Brower does not show details. Are they incompatible?Or is there something wrong with my trap code?

```
  public void test () throws IOException {

TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
transport.listen();

CommunityTarget cTarget = new CommunityTarget();
cTarget.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
cTarget.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
cTarget.setAddress(new UdpAddress("192.168.**.***" + "/" + 162));
cTarget.setRetries(2);
cTarget.setTimeout(5000);

PDU pdu = new PDU();
pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.sysUpTime,new OctetString(new Date().toString())));
pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapOID, new OID("1.3.6.1.4.1.48183")));
pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapAddress, new IpAddress("172.24.8.132")));
pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID("1.3.6.1.4.1.48183.1"), new OctetString("Major")));
pdu.setType(PDU.NOTIFICATION);

Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);
System.out.println("Sending V2 Trap... Check Wheather NMS is Listening or not? ");

snmp.send(pdu, cTarget);
snmp.close();
```

}
[image]

Using this code can receive information on the command line, but mib Brower cannot display it
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
long startTime = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getStartTime();
long sysUpTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 10000000;
pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.sysUpTime, new TimeTicks(sysUpTime)));
```

Incorrect setting results in mismatching

Answer (score 0):

seems the mib browser is binded to 162 port to get traps, the same port used by snmp4j jar to receive trap.
since 162 port can be binded to one application at a time, so both cannot run simultaneously.